# fsockeopen - knowing when timeout is triggered

Tags: timeout, fsockopen

fsockeopen returns a SOCKET_ETIMEDOUT integer when the connection timeout is reached.

If we put a *wrong* **host** or a wrong **port**, do we get a timeout error as well?

(sorry, I'm on production server, and I need to know this by theory).

Thanks,
MEM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we put a wrong host, we got another error.
If we put a wrong port, we do get a timeout error as well.